# How to update correctly an M:N relationship?

Tags: c#, model

i have a simple relationship m:m between classes `Thing` and `People` but my solution when going to update a record need to delete previous record and then create the new

Example:

#### My tables

- People (PeopleId, Name)
- Thing (ThingId, Name)
- PeopleHasThing (PeopleId, ThingId)

#### My Model

PeopleModel.cs

```
    // The following method works!
    // I've tried but I have my doubts about deleting records
    public static void Update(PeopleModel p)
    {
        using (_context = new myDataContext())
        {
            var result = (from r in _context.People
                         where r.PeopleId == p.PeopleId
                         select r).SingleOrDefault();
            
            if (null == result) return;

            result.Name = p.Name;

            PeopleHasThing.DeleteAllByPeopleId(result.PeopleId);

            EntitySet<PeopleHasThing> set = new EntitySet<PeopleHasThing>();

            //HasThing = List<ThingModel>
            //ThingModel: { (Int32)ThingId, (bool)IsMarked. (string)Description }

            m.HasThing.ForEach(e =>
            {
                if (e.IsMarked)
                {
                    set.Add(new PeopleHasThing
                    {
                        ThingId = e.ThingId,
                        People = result
                    });
                }
            });

            result.PeopleHasThing = set;

            _context.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }
```

ahd the question is **How to update correctly an M:N relationship?**

Comment: Updating a record and deleting then creating a new record are not the same thing

Comment: you're right, but for ow my process is done that way and i see is wrong. can you help me to update m:m relationship in other way?